# A fair die is tossed independently 1,200 times. Find the approximate probability that the number of ones X is such that $180 ≤ X ≤ 220$ (Use CLT).

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

The probability of getting an one is 1/6. It follows a binomial distribution with $n=1200$ and p=1/6.

So $\mu=np=1200*(1/6)=200$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{np(1-p)}=\sqrt{1200*(1/6)*(5/6)}=12.91$.

Standardizing the values then using the Z-table:

$z1=\frac{180-\mu}{\sigma}\rightarrow \frac{180-200}{12.91} \rightarrow -1.55$

$z2=\frac{220-\mu}{\sigma}\rightarrow \frac{220-200}{12.91} \rightarrow 1.55$

$P(-1.55 \leq Z \leq 1.55) = 0.9392$. So the probability of having $180 \leq X \leq 220 $ is 93.92%.

Is my answer correct?

Comment: Almost. It looks like you did not look up the z-scores correctly or misinterpreted how to use the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct through the calculation of the z-scores $z_1$ and $z_2$. When you look up the standard normal values that correspond to them, the tables or calculators provide $P(Z\leq z)$ which is usually shown as a shaded region under the bell curve from $z$ all the way to the left.

in this case, $P(Z\leq 1.55) = .9394$ and this represents a close approximation to $P(X\leq 220)$.

By the symmetry of the bell curve you can work out (or just look up) that

$P(Z\leq -1.55) = 1- P(Z\leq 1.55) = .0606$

Finally based on this, $P(180\leq X \leq 220) \approx P(-1.55\leq Z \leq 1.55) = .9394-.0606 = 87.9\%$